# 'Int' object is not iterable. But, it is a string

Tags: python, for-loop

This is a part of a script. It should get the numbers before a name which will be always the same (in the case `cows`)

```
cows = "111 cows 222 cows "
for cow in cows.find(" cows "):
    startingpos = cow-4
    print(cows[startingpos:cow])
```

The result should be:

```
111 
222
```

But, I am getting

```
TypeError: 'Int' object is not iterable
```

even though `cows` is a string, not an integer, why?

Comment: It looks like what you really want is `cows.split(" cows ")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`str.find()` returns an `int`, not a `str`.

Try the following:

```
cows = "111 cows 222 cows "
print cows.split(" cows ") # this prints ['111', '222', '']
```

The last empty entry is probably undesired and can be removed easily:

```
cows = "111 cows 222 cows "
cows_lst = [cow for cow in cows.split(" cows ") if cow]
print cows_lst # now it prints ['111', '222']
```

Answer (score 4):

`find` returns the index where the substring was found (as an integer) or -1 if no substring match is found.  In either case, the result is an integer which isn't iterable.

Perhaps you would be better off doing something like:

```
for cow in cows.split(' cows '):
    print cow
```

Answer (score 1):

`for cow in cows.find(" cows ")`:

Here, `find()` returns an integer index, which cannot be iterated over.

Read about the [`find`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method.

Were you perhaps looking for `split()`?

```
>>> "111 cows 222 cows ".split(" cows ")
['111', '222', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

help on `str.find` :

```
>>> print str.find.__doc__
S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int        #returns an integer

Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

Return -1 on failure.
```

Perhaps you wanted to do something like this, solution using `str.find`:

```
cows = "111 cows 222 cows "
start = 0                          # search starts from this index
cow = cows.find('cows', start)     # find the index of 'cows'
while cow != -1:                   # loop until cow != -1
    startingpos = cow - 4
    print(cows[startingpos:cow])   
    start = cow + 1                # change the value of start to cow + 1
                                   # now search will start from this new index
    cow = cows.find('cows', start) #search again
```

**output:**

```
111 
222
```